# What is the Git branching strategy with agile process?

Tags: git, svn, branch, agile, git-branch

We have one central repository and three different environments ie. development, staging and production. We followed the Agile process. Each sprint (10 day's work) will contain the lot of User Stories (enhancement) and Defects (bugs). We are using the GIT and deploy the master branch using capistrano build script.

1. We don't want different repositories for each environment.
2. Master repository always the stable version and points to production environment.
3. Some time client not approve the user stories and keep it on hold but they want see on staging and not on live.
4. We want to keep releases for each sprint like sprint 1, sprint 2 for version control.

So what will be the best branching strategy to use in these cases?

Answer (score 3):

Use one repository with multiple branches. Develop each story on a feature branch. When complete, merge to a development branch. At the end of each sprint, if the team is happy with all complete user stories on your development branch, merge to a staging branch. This will become your UAT branch as such. Each time you merge to a staging branch, tag your release with a sprint reference. Once you get client approval, you can then merge your release to the master branch.

Take a look at [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for more information.